# Immediately close bootstrap popover when exiting element?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popover

We have a bootstrap popover we are using and its loaded by:

```
    $('a[rel=popover]').popover({
        placement: 'top',
        trigger: 'hover',
        animation: 'false',
        delay: 0
    });
```

There are a number of items on the page (think cover art) and when you exit the first and move to the second there is a delay before the first one closes even though animation is off and the delay is 0. Is there a way to close the any others before the next one loads?

Note, the user is not clicking anything outside merely hovering over the next item with rel=popover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use it like this:

```
$('a[rel=popover]').popover({
    placement: 'top',
    trigger: 'hover',
    animation: false,
    delay: { show: 100, hide: 1 }
});
```

Comment: Hmm, yeah it definitely doesn't immediately close the popover. There is always about a 1 second (not ms) delay before it goes away. So if you have 5 items across and they all have popovers, then you can mouse across and for a few seconds all the popovers are exposed. I would love for them to close as soon as another is fired or when you move out of the element its attached too.

Comment: have you tried it? Because values for show and hide are defined as miliseconds, not seconds.

Comment: Yes, and actually I was using 0 before which should have been instantly. It still seems to be slightly sluggish. Could anything be overwriting the options? Its all I can think of.

Comment: But have you tried 1, because in my experience for some reasons 0 was set back to defaults or something(didn't analyse the code tho) but 1 worked. Also try to use simple boolean false instead of string 'false' for animation property.

Comment: seems to work perfectly when you set animation to false (without quotes), even if hide is set to zero

Comment: Setting animation to false (without quotes) in the answer I needed! Thanks @tocallaghan